# Laravel 4: Checking if an email is real during registration

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

I need to check if the email the user enters during registration is valid/real, meaning they can't just enter whatever they want as long as it meets the proper email format, I need to actually be able to send mail to it.

I also don't want to do email confirmation, though, where the user would have to click a link from an email to register.  I just want it to verify on the spot.

Comment: The best i think you could do, would be to verify the domain exists, even then it wont work for all

Comment: The only way to know it's valid is the way you don't want to do it, so ..?

Comment: You could validate that the domain exists, connect to the SMTP server and even attempt to send mail to the user. A properly configured SMTP server wouldn't tell you if a user exists or not, it would accept all mail and discard mail to a user that doesn't exist.  There is no real way to validate outside of user intervention.

Answer (score 1):

You can do all the validation you want, but in the end the best and only way is to send an email with a verification link.

Also, because there is a huge amount of valid and odd emails that you would think aren't, the idea is generally to have fairly loose validation. [Take a look here](http://isemail.info/_system/is_email/test/?all) for all sorts of interesting emails.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a DNS lookup on the MX record for the domain, then make sure that mx domain is contactable. I think that is about as close as you can get.

You might also consider letting a 3rd party do the validation for you - e.g. implement Google OAuth as a method of registration for your site.

Comment: apart from using bandwidth and cpu, this achieves nothing

Comment: Not true. It will catch those people entering gibberish domain names and domain names with no mail configured. Achieves little, I would agree with.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Laravel (you've mentioned it as a tag for the question) I suggest you to use such a Laravel's native feature as Validation: [Laravel 3](http://three.laravel.com/docs/validation) / [Laravel 4](http://laravel.com/docs/validation).
Below is how I use it in POST controller:

```
// Rules for form validation
$rules = array(
        'email'    => array('required', 'email', 'unique:users,email'), // Email is required and should satisfy E-mail format and it should be unique for table users.
);

// Form validation
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if($validation->fails()) {
    // Flash validator with input values and errors to some controller
        Former::withErrors($validation);
        return Redirect::to_action('some.controller')
            ->with_input()
            ->with_errors($validation);
    }

}
```

In general PHP usage case you can check it using PHP's native function like this:

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

Comment: This does format validation, which is fine, but can't verify whether the email is real or not.